# OpenApi Codegen

Tags: java, enums, openapi-generator

I am using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin to scaffold clients in our Spring Boot application. It uses these generated artifacts to connect with 3rd party apis. It works well except one server has been making frequent changes to a string enum value. The format in the open-api definition is something like:

```
"type": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "PARLAY",
    "STRAIGHT",
    "FUTURE",
    "TABLE",
    "SLOT"
  ]
}
```

Once the POJO that corresponds the Schema type is generated this is somewhat reasonable rendered as an Enum:

```
public enum LedgerEntryReasonEnum {
   PARLAY("PARLAY"),
   STRAIGHT("STRAIGHT"),
   FUTURE("FUTURE"),
   TABLE("TABLE")
}
```

The problem is any changes here, such as new or renamed values break our system in prod. Because of the specifics of our operational excellence we choose not to worry about this specific field but rather, treat **all** enums as strings to avoid the risk of introducing a regression.

Is there a way to configure the open-api configuration to set up type mappings for enums to String? Here is what my current configuration looks like:

```
<configuration>
    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/third-party-api.json</inputSpec>
    <generatorName>java</generatorName>
    <library>webclient</library>
    <apiPackage>integrations.thirdparty.api</apiPackage>
    <invokerPackage>integrations.thirdparty.invoker</invokerPackage>
    <modelPackage>integrations.thirdparty.model</modelPackage>
    <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</output>
    <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
    <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
    <skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>true</skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>
    <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
    <configOptions>
        <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tested the `enumUnknownDefaultCase`? It seems like a perfekt match for your problem. https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java

Comment: it is pretty good and what I ended up doing. My only quibble with it is that you lose the original value in the process of serializing